# Thursday 6th of April 2017 to date via pregmatch php

Tags: php, preg-match

Still learning PHP, i know general programing but the having a hard time to convert the following string to date

Date format is as follows

Thursday 6th of April 2017

Hi, Still learning PHP, i know general programing but the having a hard time to convert the following string to date Thursday 6th of April 2017. I can Explode using space as separator and then remove the letters from the date and the month i can do a with an array but i have i think pregmatch should be able to solve this but have not been able to figure out the right combination. Any help will be apreciated..

I can Explode using space as separator and then remove the letters from the date and the month i can do a with an array to convert to number month but i have seen examples with pregmatch and that should be able to solve this but have not been able to figure out the right combination. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, might be it will helpful to you.

```
$date = "Thursday 6th of April 2017";
$date = str_replace("of ", "", $date);
$d = date_create_from_format('l jS F Y', $date);
echo date_format($d, "Y-m-d"); //2017-04-06
```